# Configure tomato firewall in VM or Debian / CentOs server

Tags: router, debian, firewall, make, tomato

I want to use tomato as my internal firewall for accept/block network packets inside my server system. I know that tomato provides firmware for some routers but I want to do some tricky but don't know I am on right way or not.

I have downloaded source code for tomato from, http://liquidtelecom.dl.sourceforge.net/project/tomatofirmware/tomato/1_28/TomatoSource_1_28.tar.bz2

After that I followed steps provided in README file inside tar.bz2. on my Debian server. I have pasting same here also.

README file, http://pastebin.com/MJt5GFnn

I have followed all these steps, But stuck in make command. It gives so many errors which are pasted here as it is.

Make Error, http://pastebin.com/NcW95ZK2

Please help me to sort out this. Any help will be appreciable.